# Codeigniter - views in subfolders routes

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

For organizational purposes I need to have subfolders in my views directory. For example for managing login / registration: `views/login_reg/login.php` and `views/login_reg/register.php`.

In my URI want to see: `www.mysite.com/login` or `www.mysite.com/register` instead of `www.mysite.com/login_reg/login`.

I have tried the following in routes:

```
$route['(:any)/login'] = 'login_reg/login';
```

Which does not work.

**EDIT:**

A simple example to elaborate further:

```
//Controller: login_reg.php

class Login_reg{

    function login(){
        $this->load->view('login_reg/login');
    }

    function register(){
        $this->load->view('login_reg/register');
    }

}

 //Routes:
 $route['login_reg/(:any)'] = 'login_reg/$1';
```

So my URI looks like this: `www.mysite.com/login_reg/login`, or `www.mysite.com/login_reg/register`

So I want one controller to manage all login / registration related views. But I do not want to see the controller name in the URI. Is this possible? Or is the best approach to have a controller for login, a controller for registration, a controller for password changing etc? This seems a bit excessive. I want to have my files well organised into related directories as this is part of a very large site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you don't need routing at all.

Simply add your folder name while loading view.

For example your controller name for login is like

```
function login()
{
  //code goes here
  $this->load->view('login_reg/login');
}
```

and similar for register.

Hope this helps you.Feel free to let me know if you further queries.

--- Update ---

To hide controller name make chanes in route.php like this;

```
$route['login'] = 'login_reg/login';
$route['register'] = 'login_reg/register';
```

and your url will go like this now :

```
http://yourwebsite.com/login
```

Comment: Thanks @Zeeshan. Perhaps I didn't explain well enough to begin with. See edit above.

Comment: Wow, so simple, duh! Thanks.

Comment: Please help check my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360697/link-to-view-inside-subfolder-does-not-display-correctly

Comment: @SaggyManateeAndSwanFolk Can you link or mention your specific problem. So, that i can help.